# Are "sounds natural" and "is natural-sounding" interchangeable?

Tags: word-usage

Consider these sentences

> this expression **sounds natural**
>
> this expression **is natural-sounding**

I guess both mean exactly the same.

However, I found "[sounds natural](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22sounds%20natural%22)" is more commonly used than "[natural-sounding](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22natural-sounding%22)" on ELL.

Are "sounds natural" and "is natural-sounding" interchangeable in any cases?

Comment: _Sounds_ is a verb, while _natural-sounding_ is a compound adjective, so they are not directly interchangeable.

Comment: You shouldn't change your question to invalidate answers that have already been given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both forms are essentially interchangeable, but ironically `sounds natural` sounds more natural (is more natural-sounding) than `natural-sounding`.

I think you will find that this is often the case with hyphenated words - it takes a little more effort to work out the exact semantics as complexity increases, so simpler versions usually sound more natural.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is incorrect as Kate Bunting first pointed out in a comment on the question.

Comment: @CJDennis  Yet both the examples given by the OP, and the example given in my answer are essentially interchangeable, aren't they?

Comment: "This expression natural sounding" is ungrammatical as is "This expression is sounds natural". The OP changed their question after our answers were given.

Answer (score 0):

> *Sounds* is a verb, while *natural-sounding* is a compound adjective, so they are not directly interchangeable. – Kate Bunting

For example:

> This sentence **sounds** natural.
>
> This sentence **is** natural sounding.
>
> This **is** a natural sounding sentence.

I've emphasised the verbs to highlight the differences between the sentences.